# Checkbox/RadioButton to select and deselect all checkboxes within a popup

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I have a list of check boxes that I want to be able to select and deselect them all at once, how would |I do this using a check box?

The mxml of the check boxes I have are below:

```
<mx:VBox>
    <mx:CheckBox id="newCB" label="NEW" selected="true" change="onCheckboxChange(event)" />
    <mx:CheckBox id="tradeCB" label="TRADE" selected="true" change="onCheckboxChange(event)"/>
    <mx:CheckBox id="amendCB" label="AMEND" selected="true" change="onCheckboxChange(event)" />
    <mx:CheckBox id="cancelCB" label="CANCEL" selected="true" change="onCheckboxChange(event)" />
</mx:VBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use, for example, a button to select or deselect all your check boxes like this :

```
<mx:VBox id="box">
    <mx:CheckBox id="newCB" label="NEW" selected="true" change="onCheckboxChange(event)" />
    <mx:CheckBox id="tradeCB" label="TRADE" selected="true" change="onCheckboxChange(event)"/>
    <mx:CheckBox id="amendCB" label="AMEND" selected="true" change="onCheckboxChange(event)" />
    <mx:CheckBox id="cancelCB" label="CANCEL" selected="true" change="onCheckboxChange(event)" />
</mx:VBox>
```

Then

```
var num_children:int = box.numChildren;
var selected:Boolean = true;

for(var i:int = 0; i < num_children; i++)
{   
    var checkbox:CheckBox = CheckBox(box.getChildAt(i));
        checkbox.selected = ! selected;
}
```

**Edit :**

You have just to inverse the `selected`, then :

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < num_children; i++)
{   
    var checkbox:CheckBox = CheckBox(box.getChildAt(i));
    if(checkbox.selected == selected) checkbox.selected = ! selected;
}
selected = false;
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: This would only work if the check boxes were already all selected or all unselected, if there are 2 selected boxes and 3 that are not selected, it would switch the properties on all 5 and be 3 selected and 2 not selected checkboxes.

Comment: @Jordan.J.D I know that, and OP should know that. Of course it was just an example. OP can use a Boolean, for example, to set the selection.

Comment: What is box in this case?

Comment: @pconn222 `box` is the id of the `VBox` : `<mx:VBox id="box"><!-- .. --></mx:VBox>`, sorry, I didn't put that in my answer.

Comment: No problem thanks, is there anyway round the issue above? say if 2 are selected and a user want to select all, to keep the 2 already selected and select the rest also?

Comment: Yes I understand, this creates a problem on the change event I have on each checkbox, the button works although it never triggers that the state of the checkbox has changed in order to trigger this event

Comment: @pconn222 Which kind of problem do you have ?

Comment: Once a single checkbox is clicked or unclicked it triggers the onCheckboxChange(event) to either remove or add the selected item to the array. Although once the button is clicked for selecting/deseleting all this is never triggered

Comment: @pconn222 The `change` event is fired only after the user interaction. You can use, for example, a function to set that array, which you can call inside your both events handlers ...

Comment: if(selected){
     //init();
     
     // var index:int = selectedEvents.indexOf(eventName);
      
      for each(var eventName:String in eventNames){
      if(selectedEvents.indexOf(eventName)==-1){
       selectedEvents.push(eventName);
      }
     }
    }
    
    else{
     for each(var eventName:String in eventNames){
     var index:int = selectedEvents.indexOf(eventName);
     if(index>-1){
      selectedEvents.splice(index,1);

Comment: Not sure where I can post this to look decent but this is what happens once user ticks/untick a single select box

Answer (score 0):

I made a little sandbox app for you to show the use of view states. On button click it changes the state, and the checkboxes' `selected` properties can be bound to the state.

**By using states**

```
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout/>
    </s:layout>
    <s:Button click="onClick()" label="{this.currentState=='check'?'uncheck':'check'}"/>

    <mx:VBox>

        <mx:CheckBox id="newCB" label="NEW" selected="true" selected.check="true" selected.uncheck="false"/>
        <mx:CheckBox id="tradeCB" label="TRADE" selected="true" selected.check="true" selected.uncheck="false"/>
        <mx:CheckBox id="amendCB" label="AMEND" selected="true" selected.check="true" selected.uncheck="false"/>
        <mx:CheckBox id="cancelCB" label="CANCEL" selected="true" selected.check="true" selected.uncheck="false"/>

    </mx:VBox>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

[image]
[image]

**By using a loop**

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <fx:Script><![CDATA[

        [Bindable]
        private var checkAll:Boolean = false;

        public function onClick():void {
            for each(var c:CheckBox in checkboxes.getChildren()){
                c.selected = checkAll;
            }
            checkAll = !checkAll;
        }
        ]]></fx:Script>


    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout/>
    </s:layout>
    <s:Button click="onClick()" label="{checkAll?'check all':'uncheck all'}"/>

    <mx:VBox
            id="checkboxes">

        <mx:CheckBox id="newCB" label="NEW" selected="true"/>
        <mx:CheckBox id="tradeCB" label="TRADE" selected="true" />
        <mx:CheckBox id="amendCB" label="AMEND" selected="true" />
        <mx:CheckBox id="cancelCB" label="CANCEL" selected="true"/>

    </mx:VBox>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Comment: I get selected.check and selected.uncheck - State-specific property syntax 'selected.uncheck' is unsupported for MXML language

Comment: @pconn222 what version of flex are you using?

Comment: I am unsure, using Flash Builder 4.6

Comment: Is there another way to do this? my version is older than 2009

Comment: @pconn222 , you can try akmozo's solution, do you understand it?

Comment: No really, unsure on how I would link the button to the check-boxes that way

Comment: @pconn222 I am updating to use a button to check / uncheck all with a simple loop.